# Creating oscilloscope controls with LabVIEW 

Tags: labview, oscilloscope

I am creating simple application in NI LabVIEW - Lissajous Curves from signal generated by NI Elvis.

[image]

I have already added Osciloscope control and connected it to the XYGRaph. But I would also like to have some values that could be changed. I would like to have options to set values like in this image:

[image]

How can I Add them to my project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two highlighted controls look like 'Dial' controls which can be found on the 'Numeric' palette on the 'Modern' control palette (also in 'Classic' and 'Silver' depending on you LabVIEW version).

Looking at the Vertical Position control this has the numeric indicator visible which can be show by right clicking on the dial, and from the menu move across 'Visible Items' and select 'Digital Display'.

The Scale Volts dial looks to have some kind of drop down menu which I guess would have pre-set values. You could use an enumerated data type for this and code you user interface event structure to sync these two. Your user interface event structure could also update the properties of the graph (use a Property Node from the 'Application Control' Pallet  of the 'Programming' section of the Block Diagram 'Functions Pallet') to change the displayed range (Scale Volts).

Have you looked at the example code from the image block diagram?

Answer (score 0):

The two highlighted boxes are known as Knob controls. There are a variety of controls for changing values in LabView.

Please see the below figure to understand what I am trying to explain.

1. This is how you get the knob controls:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sICHw.png

1. How to assign the values to the min and max of the control can be changed from the knobs property. Right click -> property. see below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxfsC.png

If you have any further questions, don't fail to read up the help from Labview. Its quite useful and very demonstrative.